# Got to url on:click Sapper

Tags: svelte, sapper

I want to link a button to a relative path in Sapper. Is there a better way than this?

```svelte
<button onclick="window.location='signup';">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: Yes, there is Sapper's goto https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#goto_href_options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the purpose of this button is to only redirect the user to another page please directly use an anchor and style it as a button:

```html
<a class="btn" href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
```

It will make your app more SEO friendly.

Answer (score 3):

```svelte
<script>
  import { goto } from '@sapper/app';
</script>

<button on:click={() => goto('/signup')}>Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.